# Decomposition of Two-Particle Statistic in Chern-Simons Theory

Tags: condensed-matter, chern-simons-theory, anyons

In Fradkin's book "Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics," the statistic of two particles under the Chern-Simons theory is examined. While I understand how the writhing numbers $R(\Gamma)$ of single loops $\Gamma$ can be calculated from the Wilson loop of the Chern-Simons theory, I am confused about the two-particle case with the space-time loop $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Specifically, I do not understand how $R\left(\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2\right)$ can be decomposed into writhing numbers of individual paths and the linking number (as shown in equation (10.120) in the book), which is given by: $$R\left(\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2\right)=R\left(\Gamma_1\right)+R\left(\Gamma_2\right)+2 \bar{R}\left(\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2\right)$$.